# how to get the number of elements in a mongodb Array using Mongodb C driver?

Tags: c, arrays, mongodb

I have the following code written in C for using C mongodb driver .

```
  else if (0 == strcmp(key, "Records")){
            printf("-------------Records-------------\n");
            if (BSON_ITER_HOLDS_ARRAY(&iter)) {
                bson_iter_array(&iter, &array_len,&array);
                bson_iter_recurse(&iter, &child);
                while (bson_iter_next(&child)) {
                    key = bson_iter_key(&child);
                    if (BSON_ITER_HOLDS_DOCUMENT(&child)){
                        ReadRecords(&child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically I am trying to read a document from mongodb. The structure of the docuemnt is like this snapshot: http://1drv.ms/1BAXAOx

But for my api pupose I want to know the size of the array before I start iterating thru each elements and use it in my format.

As you can see I have tried bson_iter_array(&iter, &array_len,&array); but this I think is not what I want. Here is the documentation of it http://api.mongodb.org/libbson/current/bson_iter_array.html. Which says array_len is actually "A location for the buffer length".

So could someone please help how to get the array count of the mongodb array while iterating through the document.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I have the same question.  All I can think is to iterate once through the document to count elements and a second time to process them.  I guess bson format does not include an array count, so that is what would need to happen internally anyway.

Comment: hi, yes you are right, we have to loop over it. And just my opinion C driver is ugly especially if you have worked with C# driver. I moved back to C# driver as I did not find any major performance gain.

Answer (score 2):

bson_count_keys(bson_t *b) will return the number of elements if b points to an array.  I would guess that needs to read over the entire array internally.  If you just need a rough estimate for memory pre-allocation, then b->len gives the number of bytes in the array, from which you could get a rough idea, if the element size is constant.  I would guess this is the same number you get from bson_iter_array().

Answer (score 0):

The mongo C driver documentation is a bit lacking here, and forces you do dig through the code.  The definition of `bson_iter_array` is shown below.  Note that `*array_len` and `**array` are outputs.

```
void
bson_iter_array (const bson_iter_t  *iter,      /* IN */
                 uint32_t           *array_len, /* OUT */
                 const uint8_t     **array)     /* OUT */
{
   bson_return_if_fail (iter);
   bson_return_if_fail (array_len);
   bson_return_if_fail (array);

   *array = NULL;
   *array_len = 0;

   if (ITER_TYPE (iter) == BSON_TYPE_ARRAY) {
      memcpy (array_len, (iter->raw + iter->d1), sizeof (*array_len));
      *array_len = BSON_UINT32_FROM_LE (*array_len);
      *array = (iter->raw + iter->d1);
   }
}
```